# Unable to select cell in UICollectionView with a single tap

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm unable to select a cell in my custom UICollectionViews with a single tap. Previously  I've only worked with UITableViews and had no problem with selection of cells.

Here is my layout:

[image: Layout]

and hierarchy:

[image: hierarchy]

I've inserted collection view in table view to have horizontal scroll of several rows of elements.

Cell gets selected only after long press. Short taps have no effect.
I've disabled Delays content touches on collection view but that have not helped.

Also I am looking for a way to implement single selection across multiple collection views, because each table view cell holds a collection view.

Comment: you have your `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` right ? you can log something to see if its triggering the method when tap/select to make sure nothing is blocking your tap/select .., if its blocked then there maybe some hierarchy issue maybe...or issue with setting delegate and datasource

Answer (score 7):

### Solved

UIGestureRecognizer that was used to hide keyboard was causing the problems.
It was needed to set: `tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false`.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but thanks a lot for the shared solution!